# variable.scss fetch dynamic value from database - Ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, sass, node-sass

In `variable.scss`, I have declared a variable `--prm-clr: #004c3f;`, you can see the code below:

```
:root {
   --color-white: #fff;
   --prm-clr :  #004c3f;
```

I want to fetch the value of color from a variable. How can I do it? The variable will fetch value from the database.

Comment: SASS is basically a macro language. It compiles into static CSS. The only way you could do that would be to load the style sheet from your server via an HTTP request. Your server would have to retrieve the value from the database, synthesize a valid `.scss` or `.sass` source text, invoke the SASS compiler, and return the resulting CSS.

Comment: Have you figured out the answer? If yes, please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over a certain html element and change the css attribute like this:

in your .html file you define an attribute:

```javascript
<ion-col  *ngFor="let item of dataBaseItems">
    <ion-card  [attr.item_status]="item.status"> 
        ... you card content ...
    </ion-card>
<ion-col>
```

in your .scss file you can declare a map:

```css
  $item_status_list: (
    1: var(--prm-clr),
    2: var(--sec-clr),
    3: var(--thr-clr),
  );
```

Then you iterate over the ion-col, applying the css accordingly to your database item status, for each card that matches with the status variable.

```css
ion-col {
  @each $item_status, $value in map-remove($item_status_list) {
    ion-card[item_status="#{$item_status}"] {
      background-color: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

more details about scss and use of rules you can reach out here:

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/syntax#scss

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map